# What is the difference of using nginx 'try_files' directive directly in 'server' context and in 'location /' context?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I've encountered an nginx config containing try_files directly in the 'server' context:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  try_files $uri @unicorn;
  
  @unicorn {
    proxy_pass http://some-server.com};
  }
}
```

Which looks confusing because no location is matched and it seems that the server plays a role of location, and server's directives are mixed with this imaginary most basic location. Is there any technical difference with the '/' location(code below) approach? It looks much cleaner to me:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    try_files $uri @unicorn;
  }
  
  @unicorn {
    proxy_pass http://some-server.com};
  }
}
```

I tryied the latter approach and it seems batter for me. I'm want to find out when the try_files can be put directly to the 'server' context? Maybe there was something else before in the config and now this approach doesn't make sense. Do you use this style in you configs?

Comment: This may be undocumented, but the `server` context acts like a `location` of last resort. It will only be used as a location block if `location /` is missing.

Comment: @RichardSmith, thank you! I figured it out experimentally and needed somebody's confirmation.